# Why does the brake on a 2000 Sienna click and squeak?

Tags: toyota, brakes, sienna

When I depress the brake pedal on a 2000 Toyota Sienna, every time the pedal reaches near the halfway mark, there is a discernible click. As the vehicle approaches a stop and I feather the brakes, there is a soft squeal. What explains these phenomena?

Comment: Can you describe where the noises are coming from? Also, what type of squeal are you talking about? Tire squeal? Something else? Please throw some more information in as it will help immensely with the diagnosis.

Comment: @Paulster2, the  click seems to emanate from the brake pedal (in front of me when I drive), and the squeal is somewhat high-pitched, coming apparently from all of the brakes. We have changed the brakes as often as we should.

Answer (score 1):

The "click" is probably the brake pedal switch turning on when the brake pedal is depressed.

The "squeal" is will be due to the brake pads coming in contact with the brake discs. Some brake pads are designed to squeal to indicate that they are nearing the end of their useful life. Sometimes the squeal is caused by contamination of the brake pads with fine dirt or debris.